# Is it possible to update the app without restarting the server in JSF?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, jakarta-ee, icefaces

I'm working with Eclipse 3.5, Tomcat 6, JSF 1.2 and IceFaces 1.8. Whenever I update any file in my app, I have to restart the server to see the latest changes. How to update my app without restarting the server?

The server option "Automatically publish when resource changes" is already selected.

**Update**: If I change the main file, the changes can be seen immediately. However, if I update any file used in a `<jsp:directive.include />` tag, I must restart the server to check the changes or update the main file with a fake update, like adding a white space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *Servers* view, doubleclick the Tomcat entry, go to the section *Publishing* in right top and select *Automatically publish when resources change*.

[image]

It will however not happen immediately, it will take about 3 seconds. Glassfish for example, does it in a subsecond.

Comment: This option is checked and I can see that after I change any file the status changes to [Republish] and then to [Synchronized] in the servers view. It's fine, but it seems that it does not work for files used inside a jsp:directive.include.

Comment: I don't experience this, I however have never used `<jsp:directive.include>`, just `<jsp:include>`. Which Tomcat plugin are you using? The builtin one?

Comment: When I used `<jsp:include>`, the contents of the included file do not even appear, as though nothing is really included. I have no idea why. I'm including a .jsp file -- a vertical navigation bar. I'm using the builtin plugin.

Comment: You're using JSPX, not JSP. But this shouldn't matter. How about *Help > Check for Updates*? See if WTP needs an update. The server plugin falls in this category. To exclude one or other, try creating a simple JSP file instead of JSPX. Just `<html><body><jsp:include page="include.jsp" /></body></html>` and so on.

Comment: Well, your answer to my first question is right: I should check the "automatically republish..." option, which was already done, so I accept your answer. But the include vs directive.include issue seems to be a totally new question to be posted to SO. It's really not working for me. The WTP was just downloaded, no need to update. Probably I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In fact, for changes to classes, you should check the "Never publish".. Otherwise the context gets reloaded completely (takes a lot of time). If it is set to "Never", you just get the hot-swap.

Answer (score 3):

I've used JRebel before for that http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/
It's not free, but has 30 days trial.